# How to affix the sidebar for limited area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap affix class for my sidebar. I like to limit the data-offset value. Because in the bottom I have a full width content so the side bar is overlapping that section. I like pause the side bar before this section and when scrolling up It have to start affixing from that area.
Here is my HTML and Screenshot.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

```css
.affix{
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 63.75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="450">
```

[image: Overlapping issue]

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using data-offset-bottom and simple css. Here is my working code.

```css
.affix-bottom {
  position: fixed; /* Start scrolling again. */  
  left: 63.75%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="450" data-offset-bottom="570">
```